# Assigning 2 string values into one variable in Java

Tags: java

I have a java program below:

```
package assignment;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assignment {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter your age and I wil let you know if you are eligible to vote");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        age = input.nextInt();
        String nationality;
        nationality = "ghana";
        nationality = "Ghana";
       
        if (age>=18) {
           System.out.println("Enter your nationality");
           String nation = input.next();
        if (nation.equals(nationality)){
            System.out.println("You are eligible to vote");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You are not eligible to vote");
        }
    }
 }
```

Now I would like to assign the two String values, "Ghana" or "ghana" to the "nationality" variable so that when the user enters either "Ghana" or "ghana" the condition becomes true when the program gets to check the "nation" value to the "nationality" value and then executes the statement in the "if" block.

But with my above code, the program executes the "if" statement only when the user enters "Ghana". The program executes the "else" statement when the user enters "ghana".

Please kindly help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: you probably just want to compare while ignoring the case. Look into `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: An alternative solution is to always work in a singular case, e.g. `#toLowerCase` or `#toUpperCase` on the user's input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

```
if (nation.equalsIgnoreCase(nationality))
```

Comment: Link against the official documentation, not tutorialspoint

Comment: And preferably the documentation for a version of Java that is not obsolete.

Comment: @k314159 - Google results are a mystery to me. xD Fixed to v15

Comment: Thank you @Mike B.. Using the equalsIgnoreCase() worked but I had an exclamation mark at the "if" line.. Find attached  an image here: https://www.screenpresso.com/=ernJg

Comment: @Nana_Yaw - i don't see any issue there. Those warnings can also be ignored. But what does it say if you hover over it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways

solution 1:

```
if (nation.equalsIgnoreCase(nationality))
```

solution 2:

```
if (nation.toLowerCase("ghana")) // you can use enum instead of hard coded value
```

solution 3:

```
if (nation.toUpperCase("GHANA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you assing the value ghana and the Ghana. This means that when the programm reaches the if statement the value of your variable is "Ghana". I would use the .toLowerCase method

```
if (nation.equals(nationality) || nation.equals(nationality.toLowerCase())
{
            System.out.println("You are eligible to vote");
}
```

You can check the documentation here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_tolowercase.htm

Comment: Thank you all for the support given....  I've been able to run the code successfully